# setting notification type to ongoing by using FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT as alternative to setOngoing(true) method

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I understand that there is a vary useful method setOngoing(true) for setting a notification to an ongoing type. However, is it possible to do it another way? like using FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT?  How can I use that for example to change the following notification code below to the ongoing type?

```
     new NotificationCompat.Builder(AudioService.this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("My notification")
            .setContentText("Hello World!");
    // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(AudioService.this, MainActivity.class);

    // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
    // started Activity.
    // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
    // your application to the Home screen.
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(AudioService.this);
    // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                0,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
    mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the flags directly on the notification. In order to do that, get the result from the `.build()` method and use the [`flags`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#flags) field.

Here's an example that will add the 'ongoing event' flag to any existing ones:

```
Notification note = mBuilder.build();
note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
mNotificationManager.notify(mId, note);
```

It should be the equivalent of calling `mBuilder.setOngoing(true)`.